# deploying telegram bot on Render.com permission denied

Tags: deployment, permission-denied, python-telegram-bot, render.com

I am new to python-telegram-bot and I am trying to deploy my bot on Render as a web service. Render provides me with a deploy hook and I have added the WEBHOOK_URL to start my bot **application.run_webhook(webhook_url=WEBHOOK_URL)**. It starts giving me warning **Errno 13 Permission Denied** once I deploy it on Render. I am using python-telegram-bot v20.0. Any help would be grateful.

```
application = Application.builder().token(BOT_API_KEY).build()

application.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(yes, pattern='^yes'))
application.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(no, pattern='^no'))
application.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(cancel, pattern='cancel'))

application.run_webhook(
    listen='127.0.0.1',
    port=80,
    url_path='',
    webhook_url=WEBHOOK_URL,
)
```

I have tested it on my pc locally with ngrok and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: please show the full traceback to the exception. It could also be helpful to provide information on any Render-specific setup/config/settings

Answer (score 0):

You can not use port 80 in render.
Get the port from environment variables.

```
port = os.environ.get('PORT')
print(port)
```

If this prints `None`, try:

```
port = os.environ.get('$PORT')
print(port)
```

Then,

```
application.run_webhook(
    listen='127.0.0.1',
    port=port,
    url_path='',
    webhook_url=WEBHOOK_URL,
)
```